# Testing an interface with Mockito verify

Tags: junit, mockito, assert

I'm trying to test a class which has an interface with 3 argument method.
Method I'm testing is like this

```
formElementCallback.stateChanged(formElement1, FormElementState.DISABLED, "");
formElementCallback.stateChanged(formElement2, FormElementState.DISABLED, null);
```

and this is the test method

```
Mockito.verify(mockFormElementCallback, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).stateChanged(Mockito.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<FormElement>() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object argument) {
                //matcher for formObject
                FormElement formElement = (FormElement) argument;
                return true;
            }
        }), Mockito.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<FormElementState>() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object argument) {
                //matcher for state
                return true;
            }
        }), Mockito.argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<Comparable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object argument) {
                //matcher for value
                return true;
            }
        }));
```

Since the interface is called 2 times, Mockito.verify(object, Mockito.times(1) is not working. I tried to combine the logic with atLeastOnce() but then whenever I assert formElement1, formElement2 is called too so the test failed. And even if I use an if statement, matcher scope for value and state will not be aware of the form element scope.

Is there a way that I can assert like this?

```
If argument equals formElement1, Assert state DISABLED, Assert value ""
If argument equals formElement2, Assert state DISABLED, Assert value null
Else AssertTrue(false) since interface must not be called with other form elements.
```

Edit: Solution must not be to combine 3 arguments into one and put State and value in formElement class. This is due to prevent outside classes to access the formElement itself and change the state manually. There is another implementation like this: .stateChanged(FormElementType type, FormElementState state, Comparable value);

Answer (score 0):

Can you assert like this?

```
verify(formElementCallback).stateChanged(
    formElement1, FormElementState.DISABLED, "");
verify(formElementCallback).stateChanged(
    formElement2, FormElementState.DISABLED, null);
verifyNoMoreInteractions(formElementCallback);
```

See [the javadoc for verifyNoMoreInteractions](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoMoreInteractions(java.lang.Object...)). You can do the same with [InOrder](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/InOrder.html), if that matters.

Comment: No, as I said before when I verify like this, first verify fails because of the call stateChanged(formElement2, DISABLED, "") and the second fails because of stateChanged(formElement1, DISABLED, null). That is the reason I tried to combine the two logic into one.

Comment: Mockito saves and stores all interactions. Each verify checks for a single matching interaction. Each is be specific with the default (`times(1)`) behavior. If they fail beyond that, it's probably because the matchers aren't specific enough. You don't have the anonymous inline Matchers always return `true` outside of this example, do you?